# Internet Explorer 10 Windows 8 Remove Text Input and Password Action Icons

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I am testing a highly-customized web application in Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8, since it is an up and coming release, and will likely be using my application some day. Take a look at this sample screenshot of some text input controls from the application:

[image]

Is there a way, either within HTML or CSS, to remove the action icons that are located to the right of the text and password input controls?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need to use the [-ms-clear pseudo-element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx).  And use [-ms-reveal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465773.aspx) for the password box.

This should do it:

```
  ::-ms-clear {
      display: none;
  }
```

Comment: I have to admit, that an answer, given by jeffamaphone doesn't works in IE, when it is in IE7-9 mode.
But, in IE 10 it works great.

Comment: Well, it didn't exist in IE7-9.  It may be a bug that these decorators show in compatibility modes.  I would have to ascend a mountain, ingest some of the local herbs, and meditate on it for a few days, and I don't have time for that.  The folks at http://connect.microsoft.com/ie might, though, if you file a bug there.

Comment: Win8 IE10 for a website with a meta tag like this: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"> also does not work. Presumably, because the :: selector isn't being interpreted. Another thread on topic here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/disabling-auto-clear-button-in-ie10/791c1e52-27d6-428e-80cb-206b165910d8

Comment: @pure_code `::` is the CSS3 prefix for pseudo-elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements

Comment: @pure_code read the answer we're commenting on. That's all you need.

Comment: strange, I added both in, and it did nothing, are you sure it does not need a prefix like in the example?...it was placed after the html, inline, all in one file using <style></style>.  Does order matter?

Comment: I dont know why, but putting a space before ::-ms-clear helped for me

Answer (score 22):

You should instead use this because of the reason in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739092).

```
/* don't show the x for text inputs */
::-ms-clear {
    width : 0;
    height: 0;
}

/* don't show the eye for password inputs */
::-ms-reveal {
    width : 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

jeffamaphone's answer works unless the browser is in compatability mode:

> You need to use the -ms-clear psuedo-element. And use -ms-reveal for
>   the password box.
>
> This should do it:
>      ::-ms-clear {
>         display: none;
>      }

But, when the browser is in compatability mode, the reveal icon still appears.
To get around this, force the browser into IE10 mode with this tag
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: I'm looking at a page and the only style is `::-ms-reveal { display: none; }` and I'm in compatibility mode and there is no eye (removing the style brings it back). I'm on IE10 Win7.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work if I'm stuck with a page that needs to be IE7 compatible ?
Now the css-es are ignored (and I can still see the x).

Answer (score 2):

Remove action icons from text fields in Internet Explorer 10 just use this css pseudo element

```
 ::-ms-clear { 
  display: none; }
```

Remove action icons from password fields in Internet Explorer 10 just use this css pseudo element

```
::-ms-reveal
 {
   display: none; 
  }
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, these are [pseudo-elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx), not classes.

Comment: Love me some pedantry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 8 preview but have you tried just creating a custom input field using HTML and CSS? Maybe try this : http://www.webdesign4me.nl/Knowledge-Base/custom-input-field-using-html-and-css

Comment: The above example is of a customized text input, with its rounded corners, red border and box-shadow. The "standard" text input doesn't look that much different that it did in previous version of IE/Windows. I'm just trying to remove the action icons that I pointed out in the picture above. Unfortunately, in the link that you gave me, the Windows 8 still applies the action icon.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for IE10-docmode "standard" has been posted before. 
I incidentially found some kind of workaround which is independent from IE10-docmode.
If you can live with changing the width of all inputs to a maximum of 80 pixels use the following jquery:

    `$("input[type=text]").width(80);`

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to do something with padding/margins that would have a similar effect. Haven't figured anything out yet. Besides "make a hidden div slide over the x" which I just won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best solution, but if any of the other solutions on this page aren't working for you, try this.

Place a blank background image on the :before of the input. More specifically - I had my own clear button styled like the website, and IE underlayed its own. I changed the original transparent PNG with my clear icon, with a solid background one.

Other browsers don't see a difference, and it blocks the IE clear button. Only works when the input background color doesn't change I suppose.