# C# store app. Add "X"button at the end of a textbox or searchbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a C# store app where I have a search box or a textbox. I noticed that when I enter text in either the text or searchbox I don't get the "X" button at the end of the box to clear the text.

In this example there is someone with a similar problem: [Remove "X" button at the end of a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096352/remove-x-button-at-the-end-of-a-textbox) But I want to reverse that action.

As I understand in the above link, the button should appear automatically, but it does not. Does anyone know how I can get that "X" button to appear on either a searchbox or textbox?

the boxes:

```xml
<TextBox
    x:Name="textboxNoX"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="401,66,0,0"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Text=""
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="259"/>

<SearchBox
    x:Name="searchbarNoX"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="400.998,33.478,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    UseLayoutRounding="False"
    Width="256.565"
    d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
```

Comment: why dont you post some code ?

Comment: I just add a textbox/searchbox and that should do the trick. If i'm not wrong the "X" should appear automatically in store-apps. But in my case it doesn't, so i don't have any code except for a plain textbox and a plain searchbox. but i can add those if you think that is usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah the property `TextWrapping="Wrap"` should be set to `TextWrapping="NoWrap"`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the TextWrapping property from the TextBox XAML worked for me.