# Add "X" button at the end of a TextBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My question is the opposite of this one ([Remove "X" button at the end of a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096352/remove-x-button-at-the-end-of-a-textbox)).

I have a vanilla TextBox (with [TextWrapping set to NoWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23383883)), but I'm not seeing the clear cross delete button.

This is a store/universal/winrt app, so it's a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox`.

I haven't got any overrides for the default template in `App.xaml` either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the textbox with the x delete button isn't a control in the toolbox. I could be wrong. Have you tried implementing your own as a user control?

Comment: @MikeEason, yeah, weird, that other question seems to imply it exists, but maybe only for html, and not xaml as the tags suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, you can use [Telerik UI for Windows Phone](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx). It has a textbox control with a built in clear button.

Other route would be implementing your own user control. It should be rather easy.

Comment: Taking look at namespace mentioned by OP, he is working wint WP8.1 Runtime. AFAIK the link you have posted stands for *Silverlight* controls, therefore it won't work.

Comment: Right! [Telerik UI for Universal](http://www.telerik.com/windows-universal-ui) is what he needs then.

Comment: AFAIK for now there is no TextBox control in it.

Comment: Right! Well skip the Telerik RadTextBox idea then. Thanks for correcting @Romasz