# Remove IE 10 Clear Button From Input Field

Tags: css, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

On all my inputs on my site, the IE 10 Clear button is getting in the way when I try to have a Kendo Numeric Textbox in the input.

I have looked it up here, and every single question says this is what I should do in my CSS:

```
::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
}
```

However, the Clear button is still there in IE 10 after I do this.  I have tried adding `!important` to the `display: none;`, and it still shows up.

I noticed in my CSS that is being uploaded to the site that the `::-ms-clear` that I am putting into the CSS file is not showing up at all, and I know that it is there (I put it at the end of the file).

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? There seems to be no help if this method doesn't work...

EDIT: Sorry, I should have mentioned this before.  I'm using Wordpress, so I have no idea where the code for X-UA-Compatible would go to make this work.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're saying: *"My CSS does not contain the directive `::-ms-clear` which is in my CSS file."* You need to better explain exactly what you're seeing (e.g. where *specifically* are you looking?)

Comment: Sorry. I noticed when I set the document mode to be "Standards", the `::-ms-clear` DOES show up. However, I have a blank white screen.

Comment: FWIW, this is basically a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196845/ie-10s-ms-clear-pseudo-element-and-ie5-quirks-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have selected browser/document mode other then IE10/Standard in F12 tools

Comment: I have the browser mode set to IE10, and the document mode set to IE8 standards, which it says is the default.

Comment: Okay different problem. I set the document mode to be Standards, but when I do that I get nothing visible on my page. I just get a white blank screen. Any thoughts?

Comment: Upload this page somewhere so that other people can take a look

Comment: "IE8 Standards" is NOT the default document mode. You must be overriding it with an X-UA-Compatible declaration.