# Remove “clear field” X button when Browser Mode : IE9 Document Mode:IE9 on certain inputs?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How to remove the “clear field” X button when Browser Mode : IE9  Document Mode:IE9 on certain inputs.
I use this code

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
input[type=text]::-ms-clear{
  display: none;
  }

input[type=password]::-ms-reveal{
  display: none;
  }
</STYLE>
```

It's working fine when I choose browser mode like  Browser Mode : IE9 
and Document Mode:Standards and same as it is in (IE8,IE7).But it's not working for when I choose browser mode Browser Mode : IE9 and Document Mode:IE9  and same as it is in (IE8,IE7).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove IE 10 Clear Button From Input Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643173/remove-ie-10-clear-button-from-input-field)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This only appears inside IE10+ when you emulate older modes; you can't disable it using the CSS property as it's only defined in IE10+ mode.

Dupe of

- [IE 10's -ms-clear pseudo-element, and IE5 quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196845/ie-10s-ms-clear-pseudo-element-and-ie5-quirks-mode)
- [Remove IE 10 Clear Button From Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643173/remove-ie-10-clear-button-from-input-field)
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/how-can-input-clear-button-be-hidden-if-ie10-is/8f55602f-1a6b-452d-8cb3-e4cc6034b138
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15227216/126229
- [How can I disable the clear button that IE10 inserts into textboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481577/how-can-i-disable-the-clear-button-that-ie10-inserts-into-textboxes)

Comment: its bug not only in ie10. also in ie8-ie9

Comment: @miukki No, neither IE8 nor IE9 show the clear button.

Comment: @mike: That's, of course, debatable, insofar as the omission of a means to control this in legacy document modes was an unfortunate oversight for which bugs have been filed.

Comment: This is not a dupe of any of other posts mentioned in answer. All those posts talk about just IE10 and not about IE8 or IE 9 mode.

Answer (score 0):

try this css code by add important.

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
input[type=text]::-ms-clear{
  display: none !important;
  }

input[type=password]::-ms-reveal{
  display: none !important;
  }
</STYLE>
```