# How to remove 'X' from input type="text/search" control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I agree there are many answers for this question.

such as :

[ans 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473413/remove-ie11s-clear-field-x-button-on-windows-8)

[ans 2](http://geektnt.com/how-to-remove-x-from-search-input-field-on-chrome-and-ie.html)

[ans 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643173/remove-ie-10-clear-button-from-input-field)

so on, but have tried all those, but still I was not able to remove the "**X**" from the input field.

I just created simple input control :

```
 <input type="text" id="RemoveX" />
```

here is my css :

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }

#RemoveX::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
#RemoveX::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
#RemoveX::-webkit-search-decoration,
#RemoveX::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
#RemoveX::-webkit-search-results-button,
#RemoveX::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

I am using IE 11 and have checked with compatibility mode everything is fine, I am not testing this in any browsers(since I don't have to) I just want to remove the **X** from the input field in IE 10+ browsers.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested but it should work)

```
$('#yourInput').bind('input', function() { 
   var  current = $('#yourInput').val();
   var newData = current.replace("X","");
   $('#yourInput').val(newData);
});
```

TESTED NOW:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <title>asd</title>
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myInput').bind('input',function() { 
   var  current = $('#myInput').val();
   var newData = current.replace("X","");
   newData = newData.replace("x",""); // small x if you want 
   $('#myInput').val(newData);
  });
 });
 </script>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" />
 </body>
</html>
```