# Remove IE11's "clear field" X button on Windows 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-8

Following the advice given in [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs)

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

worked great with IE 11 on Windows 7 but not with IE 11 on Windows 8.1

I also tried

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

Any thoughts on removing the X on IE 11/Windows 8.1?
Thanks

Comment: I dont know why, but putting a space before ::-ms-clear helped me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same issue and the most of the css didn't help me to remove the clear button.
I solutioned this by simply setting width and height to 0 (plus display none)

```
.someInputdisplay::-ms-clear {display: none; width:0; height:0;}
```

I hope this might be helpful!

Comment: Bootstrap 3 removes the clear button on input fields in Chrome, but not in IE, yet your code seems to work. I wonder why that isn't included in Boostrap.

Comment: Probably it worked when bootstrap 3 was released but the new IE needs that hack. The good point is that there is a way to solve it =D

Comment: I confirm that "width: 0; height: 0;" is needed to make "display:none" work with IE11. Thank you :)

Comment: ie11 on windows 10 has this same problem for me. This css pseudo class resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

Check if "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" was checked by default in Tools->Compatibility View Settings. Targetting ::-ms-clear and ::-ms-reveal doesn't work in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ::-ms-reveal for Win8 in conjunction with ::-ms-clear? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465773.aspx

```
.someinput::-ms-clear,
.someinput::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That did not help.  Thanks.

Comment: I also tried these attributes    visibility: none;
color: white;
padding-right: 20px;
display: none;

Comment: Alternatively I could keep the built-in X clear button of I knew how to catch the event that is fired when the user clicks the X.  Thanks.