# Remove IE 11 "clear field" X button on inputs windows 7-8-10

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I know this question is duplicated, but I can not make work the solution in the others pages.

I have tried all of this:

[Remove IE10's “clear field” X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Remove IE11's “clear field” X button on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473413/remove-ie11s-clear-field-x-button-on-windows-8)

But is still not working, I am working in a virtual machine on mac with windows 10 at this moment.

Note that I am not using IE compatibility.