# Remove cross mark in IE10

Tags: html, css

Have used the below lines of code in CSS to remove the cross mark in IE10 .But the cross mark still appears.Please help me  how to solve this.

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
 display:none;
 }
```

Comment: it is working http://jsfiddle.net/4rza8/. You might be doing something  else...

Answer (score 1):

The css you posted works well.

Just make sure that you have included the type="text" attribute in your input element.

```
<input type="text" />

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display:none;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/w6Zby/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another way round could be to try this:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4rza8/1/

[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739092/2091693)]