# Stop the Delete glyph ("×") appearing in a text box in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, textbox

Internet Explorer inserts a **Delete** button in text boxes. It appears as a **×** glyph inside the right side of the text box, when the box has focus and contains some text.

In our online data-entry form, there are several text boxes. Most of them are multiline text boxes and have a scroll bar. In these, Internet Explorer doesn't insert the **×** glyph.

One of our single-line text boxes is auto-populated by the code, but the user can edit the text. The user's edit persists unless they click **Reset**.
The **×** glyph that Internet Explorer inserts visually interferes with the **Reset**, so we want to hide or disable this **×** glyph:

[image]

We have tried tricking the browser, by using a multi-line textbox that has the height equivalent to a single-line text box. This works:

[image]

But only until the text box content overflows:

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to stop Internet Explorer from inserting the **×** glyph on this one text-box control or on all text-box controls in this online data-entry form?

Comment: The "x" is a CSS pseudo element that you can style, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14007839.  

Essentially you remove the "x" from all input fields using this piece of CSS:

`input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: @pfolta If you post this as an answer, i can nominate it to be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Internet Explorer's × glyph is a CSS pseudo element that can be styled. If you want to remove it from all input text fields, try this code:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

(Originally answered by minitech https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007839)