# Display clear pseudo element for input boxes in FireFox or Chrome

Tags: css, jquery-inputmask

Some people want to make the -ms-clear pseudo element disappear: [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs)

My need is the opposite: I need to have it on FireFox and Chrome too. My client noticed it in Internet Explorer and founded it very useful. I use jquery-inputmask plugin BTW in my app.
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/1172

---

Addition to the answer:
I just double checked how DataTables's column filters handle this, because I remembered that it provides clear icon on FF and Chrome. I tried it out now in IE, and the IE's pseudo element puts an extra X there! The pseudo element is the bigger one, and the smaller one which is there in FF and Chrome also is a background image justified to the right with a right margin of 5px.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a native feature that is shipped with IE10. In order to have something like that in other browsers you will need to create it yourself. Or find a library that has a feature like that.