# Kendo dropdown list clear filter not working in Edge/IE

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

This is a working example you can take

```
<input type="text" id="ddl" />
<button>Change value</button>
<script>
  var ddl = $("#ddl").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    filter: "contains",
    dataSource: {
    data: [
    {id: 1, name: "apples"},
    {id: 2, name: "oranges"},
    {id: 3, name: "apples2"},
    {id: 4, name: "oranges2"}]
    }
  }).data("kendoDropDownList");

   $("button").on("click", function(){
     ddl.dataSource.filter("")
     ddl.value(2);
   });
</script>
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/@plazarov/EmAni

[image: Initial]

Click on the dropdown list and filter it in Edge
[image: Filter text]

Now clear the filter by selecting 'x' mark on the input text field. The filter wont get cleared.
[image: Image after filter clearance by clicking 'x']

Is it a bug in Kendo control?

Answer (score 0):

You could argue it's a Kendo bug yes, see their example which suffers the same problem (in IE/Edge):
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/serverfiltering

But you could also argue that it's the browser poking it's nose in and adding this "clear" button to the input field. You can suppress it with simple CSS: (credit to [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs))

```
.someinput::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

See working example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/oguYo

Interestingly the Kendo styles suppress this too instead of making it work with the widgets, I found 2 uses of it in the common CSS just at a glance:

```
.k-widget ::-ms-clear{width:0;height:0}

.k-multiselect-wrap .k-input::-ms-clear{display:none}
```

Presumably they missed this instance though, good spot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's bug. And the previous "answer" is not an answer.
For both examples http://dojo.telerik.com/@plazarov/EmAni and http://dojo.telerik.com/oguYo you need click twice for clearing the filter.
I don't find a solution too.

But it works if you clear a selected value:
http://dojo.telerik.com/ocUlEkAd/2