# Input span appearing twice in IE but not other browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an input on my application for filtering the results below. Once a user types in any characters it uses angular to filter the results, but a clickable `X`, which is a font awesome icon, appears inside the input so they can clear it that way. In Chrome and Firefox it works fine (renders while deployed) but in IE it appears twice.

**Chrome/Firefox:**

[image]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image]

The cooresponding code is:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback"
    style="margin: 0">
  <input type="text"
      ng-model="vm.typeFilter"
      ng-change="vm.updateFilter()"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Type"
      style="padding-right:30px;">
  <span ng-if="vm.typeFilter"
      ng-click="vm.typeFilter = ''; vm.updateFilter();"
      class="fa fa-times fa-lg form-control-feedback"
      style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: all; margin-top: 10px;">
  </span>
</div>
```

Not too sure what is going on as I'm new to cross-browser development. I Have tried closing the `</input>` tag outside of the span to see if that would help but no. Also tried closing the input before the span, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with de default input clear functionality IE sometimes provides:

[::-ms-clear pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-clear)

Try changing the fontawesome class to something else and see if both icons change. I think only the right will change, while the left one will stay a cross.

If this is indeed the case, check here for a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007839/1295183

```
.has-feedback>input.form-control::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Good find. I don't use IE so I never knew that was a thing. I changed `fa-times` to `fa-plus` and the other `x` remained. So if I use that above css, I should then apply that class to the inputs?

Comment: Yes the pseudo-element selector should be applied to the input. Just to make sure the X is only hidden for inputs that have a icon added by bootstrap, I modified my answer with the correct selector.