# How to get rid of the "X" on the search bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to get rid of the "X" button that shows up when writing something in the search bar, or at least change it:

```
<input type="search">
```

I tried the following CSS:

```
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance: none;}
```

and some more webkit stuff that did not work.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @AlonEitan Looks like the question is alright. Not sure if it's been answered already.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Oh, the OP is talking about `input[type="search"]`, now I get it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs)

Answer (score 8):

I tried searching Google for `input type text remove close`. I got this result. You can use the following code to remove it on Chrome or Internet Explorer.

```css
/* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
input[type=search]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=search]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="search" />
```

I got the above code from: [Remove the X from Internet Explorer and Chrome input type search | Maxime Rouiller](https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/remove-the-x-from-internet-explorer-and-chrome-input-type-search/).

Just found that it could be a possible duplicate of [Remove IE10's "clear field" X button on certain inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following CSS code:

```
 /* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
 input[type=search]::-ms-clear {  
 display: none; 
 width : 0; 
 height: 0; 
 }
 input[type=search]::-ms-reveal { 
 display: none; 
 width : 0; 
 height: 0; 
 }

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { 
display: none; 
}
```

See more at [link](https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/remove-the-x-from-internet-explorer-and-chrome-input-type-search/)

Comment: Isn't this the same code as mine? 

Answer (score -3):

Thanks this is the code that did the job:

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

Comment: Since your question has been answered the same way, please accept one of the answers above.