# Moving or configuring ::-ms-clear in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

In IE10, a focused textbox containing a value will have a little `x` added to the right of them. This `x` allows a user to click on the textbox in order to clear its value.

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842665/internet-explorer-10-windows-8-remove-text-input-and-password-action-icons/10854498#10854498) have touched on removing this feature from the user's view, but I wanted to maintain the feature in addition to adding my own icon to the right of the textbox, such as a search icon.  Unfortunately, those icons end up colliding, so I needed to determine a way to move the icon and my searches never turned up any results.

The question that I kept trying to answer: what other properties can be used with the IE10+ [`::-ms-clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx) pseudo-element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As the other answerer pointed out, the MS documentation has been updated as June 19, 2013 to include all of the properties available to [`::-ms-clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx).  It's unclear if this applies to IE10 rather than the currently forthcoming IE11, so I will leave the rest of the answer below.

For completeness, they have also updated the documentation for [`::-ms-reveal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465773.aspx), which appears to be the exact same as `::-ms-clear`.

The answer below at least applies to IE10.

---

I cannot find an exhaustive list, which lead me to experimentation:

```
::-ms-clear {
   margin: *; /* except margin-left */
   background: *;
   color: *;
   display: none|block;
   visibility: *;
}
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to trick IE's developer mode (F12) into showing me the `::-ms-clear` properties in the style tree, so I had to try things by hand and reload the page in order to experiment.  I even tried cheating by adding `onblur=this.focus()`, but that did not work.

CSS properties that did something, and seemed useful:

- `margin`: The margin gave me a way to shift it from the right side of the textbox.  I shifted it by the size of my icons, plus 1-3 pixels to give a buffer.  Only `margin-left` does not seem to work.
- `background`: The background of just the `x`. Applying any `background` settings puts your desired content behind it; it does not replace the `x`!
- `color`: Controls the color of the `x`.
- `display`: As the question that got me here notes, `none` will hide the `x`.
- `visibility`: Seems to work as one would expect similar to `display`.

You **can** combine the `color` and `background` to **replace** the `x` with a different background image so long as it fits within the given size of the `x`, which appears to be around 20px, but that is just me eyeballing it.

```
::-ms-clear {
    color: transparent;
    background: no-repeat url("../path/to/image") center;
}
```

CSS properties that did *something*, but did not seem useful:

- `padding`: It affects the `x`, but never as I actually expected its effect (everything seemed to hide the icon, or at least shift it out of view).
- `position`: Identical behavior as `padding`. Admittedly, I am much more of a programmer than a designer, so this may be my own shortcoming.

CSS properties that I guessed might do something, but that did nothing at all:

- `text-align`
- `float`

Adding other CSS pseudo-elements does not affect `::-ms-clear`. Specifically, I tried `::after` and `::before` on it with `content: "y"`, and neither one got a result.

Obviously it depends on the size of the companion icon that you intend to apply to the textbox, but I use 14-16px icons and I found that `margin-right: 17px` gave the `x` a clear gap, which shifts the `x` to the left of my right-aligned icon.  Interestingly, `margin-left` seems to have no effect, but you can use a negative value for `margin-right`.

The actual CSS that I ended up using, which prevented my icon from being covered by the `x`.

```
[class^="tbc-icon-"]::-ms-clear, [class*=" tbc-icon-"]::-ms-clear {
    margin-right: 17px;
}
```

My icons all share the same base name, `tbc-icon-`, which means that the `::-ms-clear` pseudo-element is automatically applied to all of them whenever they are applied.  In all other cases, the pseudo-element behaves in its default manner.

Of interest, `::-ms-reveal` seems to behave the same way, and if you were going to apply icons to password fields (far less likely I expect), then you can follow the above example:

```
[class^="tbc-icon-"]::-ms-clear, [class*=" tbc-icon-"]::-ms-clear,
[class^="tbc-icon-"]::-ms-reveal, [class*=" tbc-icon-"]::-ms-reveal {
    margin-right: 17px;
}
```

Comment: I think the reason why `::after` and `::before` don't have any effect is not because of `::-ms-clear`, but because `::-ms-clear` pertains to `input` elements, which cannot have generated content since they don't have *any* content (i.e. are void elements). Unless, of course, something changed in IE10/IE11, which I doubt is the case.

Comment: @BoltClock I am fairly certain that you are right. I guess that I was just hoping that it was more interactive because it was special.

Answer (score 1):

One list is available on MS site, at least.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx

(But maybe I misunderstood the question.)

Comment: No, you understood perfectly right. It looks like MS updated their documentation on June 19. That's the same as the last link in my question.