# Listen to password reveal event

Tags: javascript, passwords, internet-explorer-10

IE10 has a feature that reveals the content of a password field at the click of a button. Is there any way to detect that this is happening?

Of course, I can fall back to looking for a click where I expect that button to be, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Hardly - it's going to be outside the DOM. But then, should a web site care about this in the first place?  It's a terrible feature, but that's arguably the browser's and the user's problem

Comment: @Pekka웃 By that logic, we should just show a blank page to people browsing with IE8 when it's not supported - because that's the browser's and the user's problem. Just because it's a browser feature doesn't mean we should ignore it.

Comment: @Doorknob I'm not sure I agree with the analogy. I assume the OP wants to do something when the password is revealed, for example empty the field. *That* should remain outside the site's scope because it's the user's and the browser's responsibility how they choose to deal with the issue of password security. In other words, this specific thing happening shouldn't be any of the web site's business.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well, I suppose we don't know what the OP wants, but he/she probably has a good reason for doing it (or it's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely disagree with @Doorknob's suggestion regarding IE8. ;o)

Comment: @ColBeseder Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: For better or for worse, our site has a security feature that interferes with the revealed password. As a temporary solution, I'd like to disable the feature when the password is revealed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I don't agree it is a terrible feature. The only benefit of masking the input is to prevent shoulder surfing and if you are sure you are in an environment where that isn't an issue I can't see a problem with it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842665/internet-explorer-10-windows-8-remove-text-input-and-password-action-icons

Comment: @MartinSmith It can come in handy when having really long and hard to type passwords. Visual feedback reduces the chance of a typo and having to start all over again. But I agree with Pekka웃. It's not the concern of the webdeveloper to interfere with this feature. It's up to the user if he want's to use it or not.

Comment: @Bart - I agree with that part of Pekka's comment as well it was the "terrible feature" part I disagreed with (as do you apparently). Certainly beats typing it into notepad to see it as clear text then pasting it in!

Comment: @Orangepill That's a useful link. I may use that for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as there are no answers, for future searchers, this is the best I have so far:

It's possible to hide the button by using this css:

```
::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```