# How can I remove the cross sign and password reveal sign in the IE 9, 8 & 7 modes of IE 10?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I tried following solution to remove "cross" & "password reveal" sign, but it works only in IE 10 mode. I want to remove "Cross" & "password revel" sign from every version mode (9, 8 & 7) of IE 10.

```
<style>
    ::-ms-clear{display: none;}
    ::-ms-reveal{display: none;}
</style>
```

[image: I am sharing screenshot of demo form. Please suggest solution.]

[image: Below screenshot was taken from IE7]

Comment: check out this http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: I don't know much about CSS code. So please give me more information so i can understand.

Comment: Couls you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Sorry.I never use IE.So I didnt understand the question first.have u checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842665/internet-explorer-10-windows-8-remove-text-input-and-password-action-icons

Comment: I don't think those icons are present in IE 7, 8 and 9.  maybe 9, but i'm pretty sure not 7 and 8

Comment: I am sharing image of IE 7. Please have a look.

Comment: @RaviMajithia - Changing the browser mode to IE7 is not actually using IE7.  It's still IE10 with an IE7 "emulation" mode that isn't completely accurate.  Those icons do not exist in a real copy of IE7.

Comment: You are right but my client operate IE browser this way. So i have to follow this method.

Comment: @RaviMajithia: do the users of the site use IE 10 in IE 7 mode?

Comment: @RaviMajithia: or does the client just test the site using IE 9/8/7 mode?

Comment: Put an `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag on your page to force it into `edge` mode, then you won't need to worry about compatibility mode any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using more specific CSS selectors

```
<style>
    input[type=text]::-ms-clear{display: none;}
    input[type=password]::-ms-reveal{display: none;}
    .specific_input_class::-ms-clear{display: none;}
    #specific_input_element::-ms-clear{display: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: No it's not workout. Can you suggest another solution.